# How do I measure the amount of noise in a picture? (signal to noise ratio)

Tags: signal-analysis, noise

Hi ive got a uni assessment which requires me to find the Peak signal to noise range of my photos, I was wondering if there was an app or a simple way of measuring the noise of a singular picture, any help or input would be greatly appreciated as I am genuinely stumped.

Comment: Do you need an application or an algorithm?

Comment: If you have the original image, you might be able to get noise by subtracting the original image from the noisy image and then find the variance to get SNR.